# How do you get value of a pixel from a webcam in Pure Data?

Tags: webcam, puredata

I'm new to Pure Data and am really impressed with it so far.

What I need to do is to access the webcam and extract the luminosity (or RGB, conversion is easy) values of specific pixels.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the answer is 'pix_data'.

Got the answer here: http://puredata.hurleur.com/sujet-2749-information-gem-window

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `[pix_video]` to get frames from the video camera, and `[pix_data]` to get information about a specific pixel in a given frame.